# I'm able to run a code from terminal but the same command giving error when run in a shell script

Tags: shell-script

I'm new to Unix and shell scripting, I'm able to run a code from terminal but the same command giving error when run in a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
diff <((sort doc1) <(sort doc2)) | grep -x '.\{6\}' >sample.txt
```

I'm getting this error when I run the shell:

```
/App$ sh filediff.sh 
filediff.sh: 4: filediff.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: The double brackets in `diff <((sort doc1) <(sort doc2))` don't look reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

When you run your diff command in normal shell, you are using the current shell (mostly bash).

You indent to use a bash shell for your script, but if you call your script with "sh filediff.sh" you call a sh-Shell, which is a bit different from bash.

You can call your script with

```
bash filediff.sh
```

or you make it executable with

```
chmod +x filediff.sh
```

and call it with

```
./filediff.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

The diff command works for analyzing two files and prints the lines that are different. You are not providing proper input files to diff command:

Simple modified working script is:

```
sort doc1 | tee tempdoc1
sort doc2 | tee tempdoc2
diff tempdoc1 tempdoc2 | grep -x '.\{6\}'  > sample.txt
echo "Following is difference:"
cat sample.txt
```